# What to replace MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean with in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring

I saw another question about this but there didn't seem to be a proper answer or explanation.

I recently upgraded to Spring 4 and have had some problems with the concurrency package. Forgive my ignorance but from what I can see `ScheduledTimerTask` and `TimerFactoryBean` can be easily enough replaced with `ScheduledExecutorTask` and `ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean` however I can't see anything that easily replaces `MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean`.

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not simply use the `task` namespace to schedule your methods, saves you a lot of configuration. But if you really want to do it manually you can feed a `MethodInvokingRunnable` to a `ScheduledExecutorTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by the above. I first fed a MethodInvokingRunnable to a ScheduledExecutorTask then I realised M.Deinum was entirely right and I should just use the task namespace to schedule my methods. Thanks :)